# Android news app that fetches by topic

Tags: applications, news-and-weather

I had a great news and weather app on my HTC Incredible that gave me top news articles and also let me fetch news by specific topic, for example "ebola" or "nanotechnology." Is there a way to accomplish this the Motorola Droid Razr M?

Comment: Standard Android has (or had) a News&Weather app that just did this. Else, use Google currents.

Answer (score 1):

[Keyword News](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.KeywordNews&feature=search_result) seems to do exactly what you want, although it looks like a fairly basic model of this design. You could also use [Google Reader](http://www.google.com/reader/view/#overview-page) which has a keyword entry on the left side of their page, that also has their very own [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.reader&feature=nav_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDNd).